# Parsing Files (Java)

Tags: java

QUESTION REWORDED

How would I parse a file in this format and get each node seperately?

```
<12-08-1992>
<Name1><Info1><More1><><Moreagain1>
<Name2><Info2><><Morer2><Moreagain2>
....
```

I want to print all the information that is given except the date

Comment: Doesn't look like XML. Might need to write a custom parser.

Comment: This does not seems to be valid xml (because of the `<>` parts). You will probably need to parse it manually.

Comment: Note : A Matcher on `<[a-zA-Z0-9]*>` should do it fine.

Comment: If you dont have a standard xml structure, it's not XML, so trying to parse as XML wont help you. So you either need to convert to XML, or write something custom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seems to be valid xml (because of the `<>` parts). You will probably need to parse it manually.

Here is a matcher to get all elements inside `<>` brackets.

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "<12-08-1992>\n" +
                                          "<Name1><Info1><More1><><Moreagain1>\n" +
                                          "<Name2><Info2><><Morer2><Moreagain2>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[a-zA-Z0-9-]*>");

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());

    /* optionnaly  : remove <> characters and filter date
    String output = matcher.group().replaceAll("[<>]","");
    if(!output.isEmpty()) {
      //And don't display dates
      try {
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(output);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        //Display only if the result is not a date.
        System.out.println(output);
      }
    }
    */
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
<12-08-1992>
<Name1>
<Info1>
<More1>
<>
<Moreagain1>
<Name2>
<Info2>
<>
<Morer2>
<Moreagain2>
```

You can then filter elements you don't want and remove `<>` characters.

Comment: Thats great, how would you remove the brackets?

Comment: @AllanMacmillan With `replaceAll("[<>]","");`. I also added a bit of optional code.